# T-SQL concatenate multiple records into one record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to consolidate the records from the following table into a single record per PolNo, Year, Platform, Number.

```
| PolNo | YEAR | Platform | Number | Record | memo                |
|-------|------|----------|--------|--------|---------------------|
| 123   | 2010 | pc       | 1      | 1      | The user had issues |
| 123   | 2010 | pc       | 1      | 2      | with the os.        |
| 123   | 2009 | pc       | 2      | 1      | Replaced RAM        |
| 123   | 2010 | mac      | 1      | 1      | Ordered new CDs     |
| 564   | 2009 | mac      | 1      | 1      | Broken CD TRAY      |
| 564   | 2010 | mac      | 1      | 1      | USB port dead       |
| 564   | 2010 | pc       | 1      | 1      | Ordered replacement |
| 564   | 2010 | pc       | 1      | 2      | laptop              |
```

The records will be consolidated into a single record (Record Column will not carry forward). Also at the same time the PolNo, Year, Platform and Number are concatenated into an ID rather than individual columns.

```
| ID  | YEAR | Platform | memo                             |
|-----|------|----------|----------------------------------|
| 123 | 2010 | pc-1     | The user had issues with the os. |
| 123 | 2009 | pc-2     | Replaced RAM                     |
| 123 | 2010 | mac-1    | Ordered new CDs                  |
| 564 | 2009 | mac-1    | Broken CD TRAY                   |
| 564 | 2010 | mac-1    | USB port dead                    |
| 564 | 2010 | pc-1     | Ordered replacement laptop       |
```

As you can see I joined the records in line 1 and line 6 above into one continuous memo field. I however have some memo fields that have 21 or 22 records to combine/join.

Not sure how I am going to make this happen.

Thinking cursor, but I don't have much experience and hear it's not effective. The table has around 64k rows to manipulate (which 22k of those have more than one record)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: will do, thanks Marc... my OCD was killing me trying to format it for this editor!  :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the old 'FOR XML' trick to aggregate the record text:

```
CREATE TABLE #Records
(
    PolNo SMALLINT
    , Year SMALLINT
    , Platform NVARCHAR(16)
    , Number TINYINT
    , Record TINYINT
    , Memo NVARCHAR(256)
);

INSERT INTO #Records(PolNo, Year, Platform, Number, Record, Memo)
VALUES
    (123, 2010, 'pc', 1, 1, 'The user had issues')
    ,(123, 2010, 'pc', 1, 2, 'with the os.')
    ,(123, 2009, 'pc', 2, 1, 'Replaced RAM')
    ,(123, 2010, 'mac', 1, 1, 'Ordered new CDs')
    ,(564, 2009, 'mac', 1, 1, 'Broken CD TRAY')
    ,(564, 2010, 'mac', 1, 1, 'USB port dead')
    ,(564, 2010, 'pc', 1, 1, 'Ordered replacement')
    ,(564, 2010, 'pc', 1, 2, 'laptop')

SELECT *
FROM #Records;

WITH RecordIdentifier AS
(
    SELECT PolNo, Year, Platform, Number
    FROM #Records
    GROUP BY PolNo, Year, Platform, Number
)

SELECT CONCAT(PolNo, '-', Year, '-', Platform, '-', Number) AS Id
    , (SELECT ' ' + Memo
            FROM #Records forAggregation
            WHERE forAggregation.PolNo = record.PolNo
                AND forAggregation.Year = record.Year
                AND forAggregation.Platform = record.Platform
                AND forAggregation.Number = record.Number
            ORDER BY forAggregation.Record
            FOR XML PATH ('')
            ) AS Memo
FROM RecordIdentifier record
ORDER BY Id

DROP TABLE #Records
```

Comment: You've lost me in the select with 'FROM #Records forAggregation'.  I see that as an alias to the temp table, but then below you are using the statement 'AND forAggregation.Year = record.Year'.  Where is record.Year table defined?  You aren't calling the temp table #Record.Year, but just the name without the hash.  BTW, I like your example it makes sense in a way of learning... I'm new to XML PATH.

Comment: The inner select (forAggregation) is able to access its "parent" ('record') -- 'record' is the outer, "FROM RecordIdentifer record ORDER BY Id"

Comment: this is GREAT!  I am enjoying the learning this is pushing.  What I need is to have the output from this populating a new table (b/c this is part of a migration).  I have been looking at how to INSERT the data INTO an existing table.

Comment: You can use a `SELECT` statement as the source for an `INSERT`.  For example `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2)
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Source`

Comment: WITH RecordIdentifier AS
(
     SELECT PolNo, Year, Platform, Number
     FROM #Records
     GROUP BY PolNo, Year, Platform, Number
)
INSERT INTO ExternalTable
(
     ID,
     COMMENT
)
SELECT CONCAT...
-- Thanks Mark!  It works better than I hoped!!! SLICK!  :)